# CSS Body Image stretches when on a mobile device

Tags: css, image, aspect-ratio

I have the following CSS script that I would like help with. When its on a PC it looks fine, but when its on a mobile device its stretched. Is there anything I can add to it to keep the aspect ratio please?

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Thanks all

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove `background-size: 100% 100%` it should work for you.

Fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGVJRg

Comment: I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its because of `background-size: 100% 100%;` in your code. change it to `background-size: 100%`. this may work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about aspect ratio, it's always preferable to use img tag,
and the css for image tag would be

```
   img.background-image-holder{
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

here is an working link https://jsfiddle.net/t236ngep/